# Connection error while upgrading from Phoenix 4.0.0 to 4.3.1

Tags: java, apache, hbase, apache-phoenix

1. Currently using phoenix 4.0.0 incubating for both client and server.
2. Upgraded to 4.3.1(most recent)
3. While trying to connect using the client in command line (using ./sqlline.py) the connection could not be success throwing the following error.

   Error: ERROR 1013 (42M04): Table already exists. tableName=SYSTEM.CATALOG (state=42M04,code=1013)
   org.apache.phoenix.schema.NewerTableAlreadyExistsException: ERROR 1013 (42M04): Table already exists. tableName=SYSTEM.CATALOG

Deleting the SYSTEM.CATALOG table works, but that is not the solution intended.

What is the solution/workaround for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade it to the version 4.1.x jars first and then upgrade it to 4.3.x jars. This resolved the connection issues.